# dplyr: why do individual count summaries and index summaries differ

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm creating a new column, with a count of grouped summaries within a function. Why does:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(Count = sum(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width))
```

Not produce the same result as

```
iris %>% mutate(count = sum(.[1:ncol(.)])
```

Or

```
  iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(Count = map_if(is.numeric, sum(rowSums(.))))
```

And how can I use column indexes to create a count sum for insertion into a function with variably col_names? (The original reason for indexing)

Comment: You need `rowSums` and then wrap with `sum` i.e. `sum(rowSums(.))`

Comment: and if there are cols other than numeric, would it be best in mutate_if()?

Comment: `mutate_if` will loop through each column and update existing column or create new column.  I think you are just interested in creatng a single column.  In that case, may be you need `map_if`

Comment: I've added the reprex with iris, I believe my syntax is off but also couldn't get it with map_if(is.numeric, mutate( count = sum(rowSums(.)))

Comment: Thank you for adding the reprex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be to `nest` after `group_by`,  loop through the nested 'data' with `map`, select the numeric columns (`select_if`), `mutate` to create the 'Count' by getting the `sum` of `rowSums`, and `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                              select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
                              mutate(Count = sum(rowSums(.))))) %>% 
                              #or use reduce with sum
                              # mutate(Count = reduce(., `+`) %>% sum))) %>%
  unnest 
# A tibble: 150 x 6
#   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Count
#   <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  507.
# 2 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2  507.
# 3 setosa           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  507.
# 4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  507.
# 5 setosa           5           3.6          1.4         0.2  507.
# 6 setosa           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  507.
# 7 setosa           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  507.
# 8 setosa           5           3.4          1.5         0.2  507.
# 9 setosa           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  507.
#10 setosa           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  507.
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you - that definitely worked to add the column. I believe because of the double mutate(mutate()) it's also duplicating the existing columns - any workaround?

Comment: The grouping column can be passed directly to `nest()`: `iris %>% nest(-Species) %>% ...` No `group_by` necessary.

Comment: @CoreyPembleton. That was my earlier case.  I edited can you check now

Comment: Yes, earlier by mistake I added `count` instead of `data` in the first `mutate` call

Comment: Yes, I see - changing to data allowed the data portion to be used when it's nested. Thank you for your help, this has stumped me for a while now

Comment: Also, as @ArtemSokolov. suggested, it also works.  I just want to add the group_by as it is showed in the OP's post